# SendARP function returns null mac address

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using sendARP function to retrieve mac address from client PC.It runs successfully within LAN ,it returns correct mac address of pc's within LAN. But after deployment of website on Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 it returns null mac address. For SendARP function I am using two dlls `DllImport("Ws2_32.dll")` and `DllImport("Iphlpapi.dll")`.

**How to retrieve mac address of pc using sendARP function on windows server 2008?** Any help?

Comment: You can only obtain a machine's mac address (without asking for it to tell you and trusting it) if you're on the same network link. Whatever problem you're trying to solve, getting the MAC address of (one of) the remote machines network card(s) is the wrong way to tackle it.

Comment: Thanks for instant reply.Can you please suggest any alternative method that will work in this scenerio?

Comment: I don't know what *problem* you're trying to *solve*. I know that your current attempt to *solve* the problem involved getting the client's MAC address. That's not going to work. So to suggest an alternative, I would need to know the *problem*, not your attempted *solution*.

Comment: I have scenario where I want to restrict registered user to use my website to only one particular PC which he is register for (One user registration = One PC) that user should not be able to logon to my website from any another PC using his registered username and password. How can I achieve this if getting Mac does not help. My website is built in asp.net and runs on IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter.

Comment: If such a function could be written (maybe where the `one PC` is replaced with `a fixed set of PCs`), do you not think that e.g. Internet Banking would use such a facility as a primary means of obtaining access? "If you're coming from a recognized machine, you only need to provide your password".